# How can I change sheet direction from apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, right-to-left

I'm creating a new sheet from apps script and I want that sheet's direction to be right-to-left (the whole sheet and not the cells themself). is there any way to do it from apps script code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to change the sheet direction to "right-to-left" using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Spreadsheet service is used.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Please set the sheet name.
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").setRightToLeft(true);
}
```

- In this case, the sheet direction of "Sheet1" in the active Spreadsheet is changed to `rightToLeft`.
- When `setRightToLeft(false)` is used, "right-to-left" is changed to "left-to-right".
- If you want to change it for all sheets in the active Spreadsheet, you can also use the following script.

  ```
  function myFunction() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.getSheets().forEach(s => s.setRightToLeft(true));
  }
  ```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Sheets API is used.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  // Please set the sheet name.
  const resource = {requests: [{
    updateSheetProperties: {
      properties: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), rightToLeft: true},
      fields: "rightToLeft"
    }
  }]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this case, the sheet direction of "Sheet1" in the active Spreadsheet is changed to `rightToLeft`.
- If you want to change it for all sheets in the active Spreadsheet, you can also use the following script.

  ```
  function myFunction() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const reqs = ss.getSheets().map(s => ({
      updateSheetProperties: {
        properties: {sheetId: s.getSheetId(), rightToLeft: true},
        fields: "rightToLeft"
      }
    }));
    const resource = {requests: [reqs]};
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
  }
  ```

### Note:

- When you want to check whether the sheet direction is "right-to-left", you can check it with `isRightToLeft()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isRightToLeft()) For example, when you want to check this for "Sheet1", you can use the following script. When `true` is returned, the sheet direction is "right-to-left".

  ```
  const check = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").isRightToLeft();
  console.log(check)
  ```
- When you want to change this for a lot of sheets in a Google Spreadsheet, when the Sheets API is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced.

### References:

- [setRightToLeft(rightToLeft)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrighttoleftrighttoleft)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)